# Avoiding eslint error no-unused-vars when importing for VS Code intellisense

Tags: ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, eslint

I want to have Intellisense with code-completion in VS Code when working with ES6 classes. To achieve this I import a class and add JSDoc markup to tell VS Code that this class is used in a particular method. This works fine, but ESLint complains about no-unused-vars for the import statement when I turn on this rule. The reason is that the imported class is only referenced in JSDoc but not in the actual JavaScript code.

Consider this example:

class1.js

```
import Class2 from './class2'; // ESLint complains about no-unused-vars here

export class Class1 {
    /**
     * @param {Class2} foo 
     */
    anotherMethod(foo) {
        foo.someMethod(); // Intellisense and code-completion works for foo.
    }
}
```

class2.js

```
export default class Class2 {
    someMethod() { }
}
```

Is there any way of not getting the no-unused-vars error for imports that are (only) referenced in JSDoc without fully turning it off?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NOTE: you should be careful using this in case the **import has side-effects**! (rare with ES modules but still possible if the module has any top-level code)

```
import Class2 from './class2'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

You can't really get around that in JavaScript proper...

In **TypeScript**, you could (as pointed out by joematune in the comments):

```
import type Class2 from './class2';
```

This would have no side-effects.

The right way to reference a class **without side effects in JavaScript** would be to use the TypeScript-style import within your JSDoc. My VSCode doesn't appear to pick up on the type of `Class2` (hover over it and it just says 'any' type) but you may have better luck.

Here's how:

```
/**
 * @typedef {import("./class2").default} Class2
 * @param {Class2} view
 */
```

or simply:

```
/**
 * @param {import("./class2").default} view
 */
```

Comment: Is this still accurate? I'm getting a warning `Cannot resolve symbol './class2' `

Comment: Do you have a file named class2.ts in the same directory as this source file?

Comment: Yes that's the name of the file

Comment: Maybe create a new question on SO.  It could be module resolution in your tsconfig

Comment: You can `import type Class2 ...` to avoid side effects. It always gets fully erased - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html

Comment: @joematune, I've updated the example to show this as it would be the best use for TypeScript.  AFAIK it's not supported in JS proper so the comments are still the way to go for it.

Comment: this is a nice workaround, yet the best DX solution that integrates into eslint is by @tomás-soares and should be accepted as the best answer, as a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66261985/4742336

Answer (score 23):

You can achieve this using the [eslint-plugin-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsdoc).

```sh
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-jsdoc
```

Then just add to your .eslintrc file:

```json
"rules": {
    "jsdoc/no-undefined-types": 1
},
"plugins": [
    "jsdoc"
]
```

From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsdoc):

> **no-undefined-types**
>
> Checks that types in jsdoc comments are defined. This can be used to
> check unimported types.
>
> When enabling this rule, types in jsdoc comments will resolve as used
> variables, i.e. will not be marked as unused by no-unused-vars.

Comment: Thank god finally it works!

Comment: this should be accepted as the best answer, as a solution!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an underscore prefix to work around the linter:

```
import {Class2 as _tsdoc_Class2} from './class2'; 

/**
 * @param {_tsdoc_Class2} view
 */
```

Comment: It did not help for eslint

Comment: This worked for me with eslint. I did have to move the type since I have the eslint rule enabled that requires import items to be in alphabetical order, and underscore comes before everything else.